# Rhandsontable: Conditional formatting using functions of 'value' strings

Tags: javascript, r, conditional-formatting, rhandsontable

I am trying to colour in individual cells of a handsonstable in R by conditioning on the subsetted string value of a cell:

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame( bool = TRUE,val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                 small = letters[1:10],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

###Checkboxes not Present/Entire row not highlighted
rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE, width = 750, height = 300) %>%
    hot_cols(renderer = "
             function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
             Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

             if (value == 'C') {
             td.style.background = 'pink';
             } else if (value == 'D') {
             td.style.background = 'green';
             }
             }")
```

So the above works fine, but the moment I add a function that subsets strings, the whole thing collapses:

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame( bool = TRUE,val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                 small = letters[1:10],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

###Checkboxes not Present/Entire row not highlighted
rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE, width = 750, height = 300) %>%
    hot_cols(renderer = "
             function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
             Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);


             if (value.substring(0, 1) == 'C') {
             td.style.background = 'pink';
             } else if (value == 'D') {
             td.style.background = 'green';
             }
             }")
```

I need to use the substring function to determine the first few letters of the cell content so that I may colour them accordingly. How might I do this?

My knowledge of Java is also zero. Only know R.

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to transform the value to string using `toString` method before using `substring`.

Your code will look something like this:

```
DF = data.frame( bool = TRUE,val = 1:10, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                 small = letters[1:10],
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

###Checkboxes not Present/Entire row not highlighted

    rhandsontable(DF, readOnly = FALSE, width = 750, height = 300) %>%
      hot_cols(renderer = "
               function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
               Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
               if (value.toString().substring(0, 1) == 'C') {
               td.style.background = 'pink';
               } else if (value == 'D') {
               td.style.background = 'green';
               }
               }")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, still new to stackoverflow.